# After an imageButton is clicked, how do I best disable other imageButtons, AND assign a variable with the selected imageButton’s value?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, imagebutton

Context: My Style Activity corresponds to a layout with 4 imageButtons and a regular button. I want the user to only be able to select one imageButton at a time. Upon the click of the regular button, I want to send the data regarding which imageButton is selected to my ReviewActivity while simultaneously opening my ReflectionActivity.

I have 2 questions. First, how do I dry up my code surrounding OnClick's and disabled imageButtons? Second, how do I set a variable based on which imageButton was selected and send to another activity with an intent? I am fairly sure I've done this the long/hard way. All suggestions greatly appreciated!

public class StyleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button btn_open_reflection;
ImageButton style1;
ImageButton style2;
ImageButton style3;
ImageButton style4;

public static final String style_selection = "com.example.application.hearttoart.style_selection";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_style );

    // set up image buttons for the onClick function
    style1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.style1);
    style2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.style2);
    style3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.style3);
    style4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.style4);

    // TODO: DRY up when possible, lots of repeated code here

    style1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                style2.setEnabled(false);
                style3.setEnabled(false);
                style4.setEnabled(false);
                String style_selection = "@string/style1";

            }
        });

    style2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                style1.setEnabled(false);
                style3.setEnabled(false);
                style4.setEnabled(false);
                String style_selection = "@string/style2";
            }
        });

    style3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                style1.setEnabled(false);
                style2.setEnabled(false);
                style4.setEnabled(false);
                String style_selection = "@string/style3";
            }
        });

    style4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                style1.setEnabled(false);
                style2.setEnabled(false);
                style3.setEnabled(false);
                String style_selection = "@string/style4";
            }
        });

    btn_open_reflection =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_open_style);
    btn_open_reflection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view){
                // Open Style Activity - Navigate to Activity from the Click
                openReflection();
                sendStyle();
            }
        });
}

public void sendStyle() {
    Intent styleIntent = new Intent(StyleActivity.this, ReviewActivity.class );
    styleIntent.putExtra("style", style_selection);
}

public void openReflection() {
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, ReflectionActivity.class );
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
Button btn_open_reflection;
ImageButton style1;
ImageButton style2;
ImageButton style3;
ImageButton style4;

String style_selection = "com.example.application.hearttoart.style_selection";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // set up image buttons for the onClick function
    style1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.style1);
    style2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.style2);
    style3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.style3);
    style4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.style4);

    btn_open_reflection =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_open_style);
    btn_open_reflection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view){
            // Open Style Activity - Navigate to Activity from the Click
            openReflection();
        }
    });
}

public void openReflection() {
    Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra("style", style_selection);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.style1:
            //disable other buttons
            style2.setEnabled(false);
            style3.setEnabled(false);
            style4.setEnabled(false);
            style_selection = "@string/style1";
            break;
        case R.id.style2:
            style1.setEnabled(false);
            style3.setEnabled(false);
            style4.setEnabled(false);
            style_selection = "@string/style2";
            break;
        case R.id.style3:
            style1.setEnabled(false);
            style2.setEnabled(false);
            style4.setEnabled(false);
            style_selection = "@string/style4";
            break;
        case R.id.style4:
            style1.setEnabled(false);
            style2.setEnabled(false);
            style3.setEnabled(false);
            style_selection = "@string/style4";
            break;
    }
}
```

}

[This link might help.](https://medium.com/@CodyEngel/4-ways-to-implement-onclicklistener-on-android-9b956cbd2928)